# mpdf is not working in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am using mpdf to generate pdf in Zend Framework, but when i create object of mpdf its not creating. When i am using it in simple core php then its work fine. Please provide me a solution.
here is my code:

```
    $html ='<table border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">';
    for($i=0;$i<100;$i++){
    $html .='<tr>
        <td style="height:50px">
            hi
        </td>
        <td>
            hello
        </td>
    </tr>';
    }
    $html .='</table>';
    include("mpdf/mpdf.php");
    $mpdf=new mPDF('c','A4','','',32,25,27,25,16,13);
    $mpdf->setHeader('WELCOME TO MY WORLD') ;
    $mpdf->setFooter('{PAGENO}') ;
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html,2);
    $mpdf->Output('mpdf.pdf','I');
    exit;
```

$mpdf=new mPDF(); is not working. Why?

Comment: Where have you placed your mpdf.php file?

Comment: project/code/mpdf/mpdf.php

Comment: Is there any need of Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance() ?

Comment: Are you using MVC of Zend Framework?

Comment: You need to provide error you are getting rather than a simple `it is not working`

Comment: after the line 'include("mpdf/mpdf.php");' when i am using echo "hi";die; then it prints 'hi' but when i am using echo & die after the line $mpdf=new mPDF('c','A4','','',32,25,27,25,16,13); or $mpdf=new mPDF(); it prints none.

Comment: It's likely the file is not found. You should keep in mind that in development environment you should turn on `error display` and set your `error reporting level` to `E_ALL`. This will help you debug your applications your self with explicit error messages!

Comment: thanks @php-dev i have set **error_reporting(E_ALL);** and **ini_set('display_errors', true);** that shows me the error why class not loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the path for mpdf files and it's libraries. If still you are getting any error just report here.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use include in zend framework, namespace use to activate mpdf, then filename and function name should be same.